# FindChangeByList does not work - UserInteractionLevel is undefined

Tags: indesign-scripting

When I try to run the FindChangeByList script (I quote the whole script below) from the InDesign script panel, there appears to be no result.

When I run the script from Adobe Extend Script Toolkit CC, it gets to this line

```
app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = userInteractionLevel.interactWithAll;
```

and says that `userInteractionLevel` is undefined. This happens right at the beginning of the script within the first function `main()`.

I tried commenting-out this line to see what would happen, and it got stuck on the next line

> ```
> if(app.documents.length > 0){
> Error message: "undefined is not an object"
> ```

It looks like there is a problem with the app. object? I don't know.
I could not see anyone else online with this issue.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Here is the relevant part of the script below:

```
//FindChangeByList.jsx
//An InDesign JavaScript
/*  
@@@BUILDINFO@@@ "FindChangeByList.jsx" 3.0.0 15 December 2009
*/
//Loads a series of tab-delimited strings from a text file, then performs a series
//of find/change operations based on the strings read from the file.
//
//The data file is tab-delimited, with carriage returns separating records.
//
//The format of each record in the file is:
//findType<tab>findProperties<tab>changeProperties<tab>findChangeOptions<tab>description
//
//Where:
//<tab> is a tab character
//findType is "text", "grep", or "glyph" (this sets the type of find/change operation to use).
//findProperties is a properties record (as text) of the find preferences.
//changeProperties is a properties record (as text) of the change preferences.
//findChangeOptions is a properties record (as text) of the find/change options.
//description is a description of the find/change operation
//
//Very simple example:
//text  {findWhat:"--"} {changeTo:"^_"} {includeFootnotes:true, includeMasterPages:true, includeHiddenLayers:true, wholeWord:false} Find all double dashes and replace with an em dash.
//
//More complex example:
//text  {findWhat:"^9^9.^9^9"}  {appliedCharacterStyle:"price"} {include footnotes:true, include master pages:true, include hidden layers:true, whole word:false}   Find $10.00 to $99.99 and apply the character style "price".
//
//All InDesign search metacharacters are allowed in the "findWhat" and "changeTo" properties for findTextPreferences and changeTextPreferences.
//
//If you enter backslashes in the findWhat property of the findGrepPreferences object, they must be "escaped"
//as shown in the example below:
//
//{findWhat:"\\s+"}
//
//For more on InDesign/InCopy scripting see the documentation included in the Scripting SDK 
//available at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/sdk.html
//or visit the InDesign Scripting User to User forum at http://www.adobeforums.com
//
main();
function main(){
    var myObject;
    //Make certain that user interaction (display of dialogs, etc.) is turned on.
    //app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = userInteractionLevel.interactWithAll;
    if(app.documents.length > 0){
        if(app.selection.length > 0){
            switch(app.selection[0].constructor.name){
                case "InsertionPoint":
                case "Character":
                case "Word":
                case "TextStyleRange":
                case "Line":
                case "Paragraph":
                case "TextColumn":
                case "Text":
                case "Cell":
                case "Column":
                case "Row":
                case "Table":
                    myDisplayDialog();
                    break;
                default:
                    //Something was selected, but it wasn't a text object, so search the document.
                    myFindChangeByList(app.documents.item(0));
            }
        }
        else{
            //Nothing was selected, so simply search the document.
            myFindChangeByList(app.documents.item(0));
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("No documents are open. Please open a document and try again.");
    }
}`
```

Comment: I *think* the scripting for CS products is kind of a piece-meal thing: each product has its own scripting engine. I mention this because you may have to look for, and change, the scripting engine inside Adobe Extend Script Toolkit to point it to Indesign's scripting engine.

Comment: @Yorik thanks for the reply, do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You need to generally havea `#target indesign` in the first line.

Comment: @joojaa It's not letting me mark your answer as the answer but that was it!! Thank you so much! I didn't know that...

Comment: It is OK to take the comments as prompts and then post your own answer (and accept it). This way the solution is prominent